# use custom-webpack within an esm Angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I added [custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) to my [Angular project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-mdn6pg?file=angular.json)

when I switch my project to use esm

- set `type: module` in `packae.json`
- set `module: ES2022` and `target: ESNext` in `tsconfi.json`
- use `export` in `webpack.confi.js`

but I got this error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/projects/node-mdn6pg/webpack.config.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
```

this error caused by [this line](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/74f3bc99e15a78a9e1bf669b3cb553ed77756aa1/packages/custom-webpack/src/custom-webpack-builder.ts#L75)

```
// should be replaced with `import(path)`
  const customWebpackConfig = require(path);
```

is there a workaround to build my esm project successfully without switching back to commonjs

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by renaming the file's suffix to `.mjs` so that it is interpreted as an ECMAScript module, after which the import should work in the expected way.

Peehaps the most consistent option though, is to also write your webpack script in TypeScript, and run it with this command:

```bash
NODE_OPTIONS='--loader ts-node/esm --no-warnings' webpack --config webpack.config.ts
```